# Cannot access javascript variable outside the function

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, global-variables

Why can't I access the variable `field_count` outside of `loadData()` function?

```
var field_count;
await loadData();

async function loadData() {
  var response =  await fetch('/get_data');
  var data =  await response.json();

  field_count = data.field_count;
  alert(field_count) // shows correct data
}

alert(field_count) //shows undefined
```

Comment: And where do you call loadData?

Comment: Well now with the edit, you do not await the function call.

Comment: you're right. I forgot to call it but still same problem occurs.

Comment: you mean it should be await loadData(); ?

Comment: This looks like a timing issue. The `alert()` will happen before the value is set in your `loadData()` function. Because `loadData` uses `async` the rest of your code will continue to execute. And because `field_count` was declared but not defined, when the `alert()` executes the value is in fact `undefined`.

Comment: @EssXTee thank you for the answer. Is there a way to fix it or should I find another way to code it?

Comment: This isn't something that really needs to be *fixed* (at least based on the code provided). The `field_count` variable gets set in your `loadData()` function, and then gets alerted there. If you need to use that variable somewhere else in your code but want to wait until after `loadData()` is finished, just place that code in a new function and call that function at the end of the `loadData()` function. Once `loadData()` has set the value from the `fetch()`, the next function will run and use the value of `field_count`.

Answer (score 2):

Here `loadData()` is an async function, but your `alert(field_count)` outside of any function is not async. You're doing two `await()` calls inside the function, which operate asynchronously as you've requested of the language. However, the `alert()` which is outside the function is operating synchronously. Under most circumstances, that top-level `alert()` will have run and tried to `alert()` an undefined value before the two `await` calls are completed.

Mixing async programming and synchronous programming in this way is fraught with traps and pitfalls. I would recommend until you are comfortable with the ideas of asynchronous code and how it differs from other code, set up the program first then stick to async code working with other async code. Once you are comfortable with both and understand the differences, you can consider using results from async code in sync code, but you'll need to learn about how to use promises or some other synchronization method.

Consider the output of this code.:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 600);
  });
}

var result;
async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: "resolved"
}

asyncCall().then(() => {
  console.log(result)
});

console.log(result);
```

That is going to quickly log `"calling"`, then `undefined`, then wait 600 milliseconds and then log `"resolved"` and another `"resolved"` quickly.

This part uses promises to coordinate the async function with the parent program.:

```
asyncCall().then(() => {
  console.log(result)
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise explain all this fairly well.